# How to break a SSRS Report page only in PDF?

Tags: pdf, reporting-services, bids

I am using BIDS to develop a report that needs to be configured in one page when viewed on the internet explorer but still needs page breaks for good display in PDF when exported. The problem is that when i insert page breaks beetween tables another page is added to the report and i only want that in the PDF. Is there any way i can insert page breaks in the PDF but not on the report view itself?

[image: Page is more than one]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by setting the `InteractiveSize`  property to the wanted value (0 can be used to make it infinite).
If you wish to keep the same width, then you should only change the `Height`.

[image: InteractiveSize]

---

**Edit:**  Defining specific page breaks will always force the viewer  to use paging as well. This was implemented to improve the performance of large reports to allows users to begin viewing the initial pages of the report while waiting for additional pages to become available.

> HTML and Excel output shows a report as a single page if there are no
>   page breaks. If you do specify InteractiveHeight and InteractiveWidth,
>   the HTML and Excel output formats render reports using soft page
>   breaks. Soft page breaks are placed on a page using an estimated page
>   size, which makes the size of the reports less exact than reports
>   produced by an output format that supports page size. Soft page breaks
>   are calculated at run time by the control. Although it is not
>   recommended, you can disable soft page breaks by setting
>   InteractiveHeight to 0.

Source: [Defining Page Size and Page Breaks in a ReportViewer Report](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms251701(VS.80).aspx)

As described in the quote above, the `InteractiveHeight` is used to apply soft page breaking when using the report viewer. So the solution is to only use soft page breaks.

You can manipulate your report to break correctly with paging without using hard page breaks by wrapping the wanted blocks inside rectangles. These rectangles you then re-size to be the size of a page and set the property `KeepTogether`as true.

This will try to fit the content of the rectangles on the same page, adding a break when you reach the next rectangle. Because your `InteractiveSize` has no limit, this will not be displayed in the report viewer.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but still not working. Is the page forced to break regardless of the InteractiveSize when i set up a page break?

Comment: True, I've edit my answer. Hope this helps you achieve your wanted behavior.

Comment: Wrapped all the report in one rectangle and the sub reports in others rectangles inside it. Worked like a charm! Thanks!